# Any interest for Java based (but using OpenCL for the mining) monero mining software?

Tags: mining

Few months ago I had some free time and played with the idea of creating a Java based miner. I wrote the mining part in OpenCL ("from scratch" implementation, no code is used from any existing miner).

After a lot of tunning I managed to get it on par with XMR-stak - I was getting almost the same hashrate out of my Vega 64 from both mine and xmr-stak, i.e. ~2040 h/s.

However, so far mine miner lacks the networking functionality that is needed to communicate with a mining pool. Also there is need some additional work to be done, all-in-all it will require 30 to 45 days to finish it.

I was wondering, is there in the community interest for a Java based miner? Any examples for specific use cases (like on Android for example)?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question which needs discussion. reddit.com/r/monero or the monero github repository would be probably a better place for it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've posted it there too. You are right - it is opinion-based but stackexchange contains different more technical auditory so I hope it will receive some attention here too (before it gets closed).

Comment: I see this is closed, but I'm interested. I wrote a Java-ish miner that uses JNI to call out to a .dll that implements the cryptonight hash. I'm able to get the same performance out of it that xmrig gets from my CPU. Is this discussion still ongoing on reddit?

Comment: @DanWatson I had a post on redit with the same question but there was not much interest either. Obviously the crypto community is mostly C++ based and there is no interest in Java. Which is strange because at least for the GUI wallets Java can give much better results (especially for Monero where the wallet code is kind of a hard to support mess).